# A special partition for unit interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I:=[0, 1]$ be the unit interval. Can we construct a partition
$\mathbf{P}=\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha}$ with $\mid A_\alpha\mid=2$,
that is, for each $\alpha$, $A_\alpha $ has exactly two elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $r\in [0, \frac{1}{2})$ set $A_r=\{r, r+\frac{1}{2}\}$
is partition for the interval $[0, 1)$, and since $[0, 1)\approx
[0, 1]$. Thus, $[0, 1]$ has a partition with mentioned property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can partition $[0,1]$ into sets of size two. There isn't really a good way to write it though, and I would probably just refer to it as a partition of sets of size two.